# Flush (Neo)Mutt Flags

Tags: linux, email, terminal, mutt

I wonder how can I flush flags for messages without close (Neo)Mutt or switch the mailbox. I tend to keep the window open, but I want that messages that get marked as read (more likely unmarked to be unread) can be recognized as that outside of (Neo)Mutt as well. So I have some other tools to show me unread messages with notifications etc. pp. If I read now a mail in (Neo)Mutt I wan't them to not bother me anymore.
I added a makro running the shell command notmuch new, but this has no effect. As said only if I close the program or switch the box, the flags are added or removed at the mailbox and are visible for external tools.
I was not able to found a function or command at the or nor documentation. Maybe you guys can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the answer to [my GitHub issue](https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/issues/1558) states, the `sync-mailbox` command is doing the job and is bound to `$` by default.

Comment: I was about to edit your answer and add that timeout-hook is a nice idea. Then I've found that I replied the same to Your GithHub issue 2 months ago :-)